# How to remove related items from the shopping cart even though client changed the data attribute values from front end?

Tags: php, validation, custom-data-attribute

In AliExpress I have added two items to the cart. Then inside the cart I've inspected elements and swap data attribute values of delete buttons of the two cart items. Now first items delete button has the data attribute value of second item and second items delete button has the data attribute value of first item.

So theoretically If I delete first item it should remove second item from the cart because of I swapped the data attribute values. And If I delete second item it should remove first item from the cart. But it does not. It removes the correct item even though I have changed data attribute values.(When I click remove button of second item it removes second item even though I have already changed data attribute values.) eBay, Amazon and all these kind of websites handle this situation as I know. But I can't figure out how they validate that.

Anyone can explain or give a reference to learn how to perform this kind of a validation.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably an implementation detail of AliExpress but if they are using jQuery that is known to put the data attributes in a data object when the DOM is loaded but doesn't stay up to date with DOM changes so AliExpress may be using that object (or a similar approach) rather than reading the attributes

Comment: Besides, what makes you think that had to do with "validation" to begin with? The value XYZ is either valid to be passed as identifier for an item to be removed, or it isn't. The server side has neither a _way_ to verify which button click caused that value to be send, nor does it have any _need_ to.